# User Role Selection and Profile Fields

Tags: users

I have two user roles with profile fields.

Role 1 
Name, Username, Password, Email, Address line 1, Address line 2, Website.

Role 2 
Name, Username, Password, Email

I want to let anonymous user to chose user role on registration.
Upon user role selection, I want to show role-related fields interactively (with javascript).

I mean that when select Role 2, Address line 1, Address line 2 and Website fields will be disappeared, and when select Role 1, they will be appeared again.

I currently use 'user_role_field' module and 'autoassignrole' module.
Is there another module to achieve that purpose ?
I'm using Drupal 7.7.

Here is what I'm looking for.
[Click here to download and view screen draft.](http://www.sendspace.com/file/bfvqkm)

Thank you for any help.
Rgds/Sithu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grouped the fields (Address line 1, Address line 2 and Website) by using [field_group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.
And hide the field group from jquery upon selecting role.

1) I created a js file ( mymodule.js )

```
Drupal.mymodule = {
    toggleProfile : function(obj){
        if($(obj).val() == 6){
            $('#user_user_form_group_profile').hide();
        }else{
            if(typeof $(obj).val() != 'undefined') $('#user_user_form_group_profile').show();
            else $('#user_user_form_group_profile').hide();
        }
    }
};
$(document).ready( function(){
    Drupal.mymodule.toggleProfile($('input[name=user_roles]').filter(':checked'));
} );
```

2) Included it from hook_form_alter and attached "onclick" attributes on the user role radio buttons.

```
if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
    # User role
    $form['autoassignrole_user']['user_roles']['#attributes'] = array('onclick' => "Drupal.mymodule.toggleProfile(this)");
    if($user->uid == 1){ # if master administrator, hide it
        $elems[] = 'autoassignrole_user';
    }
}
```

One drawback is that js uses "rid" from the "users_roles" table, i.e., $(obj).val() == 6 
If there is a better solution, it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) to get you started. It will allow you to assign profile fields to roles and have them available upon registration. You could then use jQuery to display the proper register form on selection.

Comment: So, I need to write custom module ??

Comment: Not sure. Can you give me more information on how you want this to work

Comment: I updated my original post with a link to my screen draft to download.

Comment: As Drupal 7 core provides a way to add profile fields, do we need to use Profile 2 module which requires Entity API ?

Comment: It seems like you could add a custom module solely for adding some jquery to your registration form.

Comment: Sketched out it would be something along the lines of a  function that would unhide a field group (http://drupal.org/project/field_group) depending on which role is selected. The issue I think you'll run into with this approach is if those fields are required, hiding them will not work.  Also, I suggested Profile2 because it allows you to give fields to a user based on role

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help. My fields are not required in this case and I should remove require if I hide those fields. I use the module "user_role_field" to give fields to a user based on role.